# Neighborhoods, convergence of quotient topology $[0,1] x N$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, quotient-spaces

I am having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around this:

*Consider the space* $$X = [0,1] \times \mathbb{N}$$ *as a subspace of* $\mathbb{R}^2$. *Define the equivalence relation* $$(x,y) \sim (z,w) \iff (x,y) = (z,w)$$ or $$x=z=0$$.  *Prove that the sequence* $$\big[\big(\frac{1}{n},n\big)\big]_\sim$$ *doesn't converge in the quotient space* $X/\sim$.

To show that this does not converge, I need to find a neighborhood of $(0,n)$ which does not contain the sequence for infinitely many points.  My question is, what would this neighborhood look like?  Would $$\pi^{-1}\big(\big[0,\frac{1}{n+1}\big) \big)$$ work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would that $n$ be?  A fixed one? A variable one?

You don't need just an open set around the point $(0,n)$, you need an open set around the *set* $\{0\}\times\mathbb{N}$; that will give you a neighbourhood of the *point* $\{0\}\times\mathbb{N}$ in the quotient space.
Try $\bigcup_n([0,\frac1{2n})\times\{n\})$.

Comment: ah i see!  thank you so much